# Alternatives for nested loops for dataframes with multiindex

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have a large dataframe with multiindex, and I have to do some simple mathematical operations on it, creating a new column. The problem is that it takes a lot of time. For now I use a nested loop for this, but I can't think of any more pythonic solution for this. The code looks like this:

```
for element1 in short_list:
    for element2 in long_list:
        df.loc[(element1, element2), ('name1', 'name2')] = abs(df.loc[(element1, element2), ('name3', 'name4')] - df.loc[(element1, element2), ('name5', 'name6')] * another_list[element1])
```

I tried to search for solutions like using .groupby or other iterators, but either I don't understand how they function, or they don't fit my needs. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, the reason that operations on dataframes are slow is because they are not vectorized. For your case, if you're able to express your operation in a vectorized form, you should see a performance improvement. This would involve performing the operation on whole columns of the dataframe at once, rather than on individual cells in a loop. Maybe if you can provide an example dataframe I can help you better, but you can try two things for now:

First it seems that another_list is accessed by element1 index, which indicates it can probably be converted to a Series or a DataFrame with the appropriate indices for automatic alignment.

`another_series = pd.Series(another_list, index=short_list)`

Secondly, you are subtracting ('name3', 'name4') from ('name5', 'name6') and then multiplying it by elements from another_list. Assuming all these elements are on the same level in the multi-index DataFrame (or can be easily unstacked to that format), you can probably do this in a vectorized way:

`df[('name1', 'name2')] = abs(df[('name3', 'name4')] - df[('name5', 'name6')] * another_series)`